# pmatrix with minimum bracket size

Tags: matrices, delimiters

I want to typeset one-element vectors like so:

[image]

In this example, `v` and `w`are vectors. In the first line I used `pmatrix`, but the expression `c(v)` could easily be mistaken to mean "function c of v" because the brackets are regular size. So even if the vectors contain only one element, I would like them to look like in the second line. However, if they contain more elements the brackets should grow in size.

Ideally, I would like to be able to say

```
\begin{pmatrix}[min=\bigg]
\end{pmatrix}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2, setspace, geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp, relsize, url}
\usepackage{xcolor, minitoc, tocloft}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, bbold, stmaryrd, latexsym}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, dcolumn, colortbl, longtable, multirow, bigdelim}


\begin{document}
$$x = c\begin{pmatrix}v\end{pmatrix} + d\begin{pmatrix}w\end{pmatrix}$$
$$x = c\bigg(\begin{matrix}v\end{matrix}\bigg) + d\bigg(\begin{matrix}w\end{matrix}\bigg)$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Parentheses being overloaded is one of the reasons why I prefer brackets for column vectors and matrices.

Comment: For me, it's one of the reasons to always indicate multiplication with a `$\cdot$`, and _not_ write function application with unnecessary parentheses. `$f\:x$` is just as good as `$f(x)$`, and `$c\cdot \vec{v}$` is certainly a lot clearer than any `$c\Bigl( v\Bigr)$` hocus pocus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define your own environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{vect}
 {\left(\vphantom{\bigg|}\begin{matrix}}
 {\end{matrix}\right)}

\begin{document}

\[
x = c\begin{vect}v\end{vect} + d\begin{vect}w\end{vect}
\]

\[
\begin{vect}
a
\end{vect}
\quad
\begin{vect}
a \\ b
\end{vect}
\quad
\begin{vect}
a \\ b \\ c
\end{vect}
\]

\end{document}
```

Never use `$$` with LaTeX.

[image]

Frankly, this doesn't really sound like a nice idea.

Comment: Why don't you like it?

Comment: @alexraasch (IMHO) Relying on the size of parentheses as the only indicator of something is poor typography, the ambiguity isn't removed by this completly, for example I will now be curious why are your parentheses so stupidly large, but I wouldn't think that it's because you want to indicate a 1-dimensional vector this way.

Comment: @yo': Ok, I agree. However, I'm not at liberty to change to, e.g., square brackets at the moment, as I am not the principal author of the article I'm writing.

Comment: @alexraasch Having your own environment allows you to change the final format as you like without modifying the input file, except for the definition of `vect`.